# Do combination of existing features make new features ?

Tags: machine-learning

Does it help in classifying better if I add linear, non-linear combinatinos of the existing features ? For example does it help to add mean, variance as new features computed from the existing features ? I believe that it definitely depends on the classification algorithm as in the case of PCA, the algorithm by itself generates new features which are orthogonal to each other and are linear combinations of the input features. But how does it effect in the case of decision tree based classifiers or others ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, combination of existing features **can give new features and help for classification**. Moreover, combination of the feature with itself (e.g. polynomial from the feature) can be used as this additional data to be used during classification.

As an example, consider logistic regression classifier with such linear formula as its core:

```
g(x, y) = 1*x + 2*y
```

Imagine, that you have 2 observations:

1. x = 6; y = 1
2. x = 3; y = 2.5

In both cases `g()` will be equal to 8. If observations belong to different classes, you have no possibility to distinguish them. But let's add one more variable (feature) `z`, which is **combination of the previous 2 features** - `z = x * y`:

```
g(x, y, z) = 1*x + 2*y + 0.5*z
```

Now for same observations we have:

1. x = 6; y = 1; z = 6 * 1 = 6        ==>  g() = 11
2. x = 3; y = 2.5; z = 3 * 2.5 = 7.5  ==>  g() = 11.75

So now we get 2 different points and can distinguish between 2 observations.

**Polynomial** features (x^2, x^3, y^2, etc.) do not give additional points, but instead **change the graph of the function**. For example, `g(x) = a0 + a1*x` is a line, while `g(x) = a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2` is parabola and thus can fit data much more closely.

Comment: Are there any libraries to accomplish automatic feature creation from existing features and validation of their impact to model's accuracy?

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's always better to have more features. Unless you have very predictive features (i.e. they allow for perfect separation of the classes to predict) already, I would always recommend adding more features. In practice, many classification algorithms (and in particular decision tree inducers) select the best features for their purposes anyway.

Comment: I do not agree with "it's always better to have more features" - how about feature selection and the course of dimensionality?

Comment: The idea is that new features (or combinations of existing features) allow you to make better predictions. If they don't they won't be chosen. You can also, as you point out, run feature selection to reduce the number of features. I don't see where the curse of dimensionality comes in here -- Support Vector Machines for example intentionally increase the dimensionality of the feature space to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

There are open-source Python libraries that automate feature creation / combination:

We can automate [polynomial feature creations with sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html).

We can automatically create [spline features with sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.SplineTransformer.html).

We can combine features mathematically with Feature-engine. With [MathFeatures](https://feature-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_doc/creation/MathFeatures.html) we combine feature groups, and with [RelativeFeatures](https://feature-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_doc/creation/RelativeFeatures.html) we combine feature pairs.